# SQL modifying rows based upon value in previous rows

Tags: sql, row, operation

I have below table and want to convert into a table as shown below it. Whenever there is a missing value in a column 'name' then the value is populated from the adjacent top row. I solved my purpose by creating a self join. But in some cases 2 or 3 rows in succession are blank and i had to run my self join multiple times. Moreover I was not sure how many continuous blanks are in the data and I had to keep running self join again and again till it stopped updating any records

i am using SQL server management studio...

```
id  name
1   nj
2   ab
3   
4   
5   cd
6   
7   ef
8   
9   
10  gh
11  ij
12  jk
```

The output that I want:

```
id  name
1   nj
2   ab
3   ab
4   ab
5   cd
6   cd
7   ef
8   ef
9   ef
10  gh
11  ij
12  jk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a select query, you can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select id,
       (select top 1 name
        from yourtable t2
        where t2.id <= t.id and
              t2.name is not null
        order by t2.id desc
       ) as name
from yourtable t;
```

Comment: i am a newbie to SQL, in the 1st from statement you have t and t2. But in the 2nd from statement there is only t. Would it create any problems? i will check your solution at the earliest....But felt that I should ask my question..

Comment: @user2543622 . . . These are just table aliases.  I added an explicit table name to make it clearer how they are being used.